# Map Option[String] to Option[Int] in JSON formatter

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Here's my use case:

External JSON

```
..
lat: "xx.xx",
lng: "xx.xx",
..
```

My (working) reader, as is:

```
..
(__ \ 'lat).read[Option[String]] ~
(__ \ 'lng).read[Option[String]] ~
..
```

All I would like to do is map the `String` to an `Int`. Since, logically, lat & long coords should be represented as such.

Here is what I tried, and doesn't work:

`(__ \ 'lat).read[Option[String]].map(_.map(_.toInt) orElse None)) ~`

My case class when trying to do the above, otherwise they're `Option[String]` and work:

```
...
lat: Option[Int],
lng: Option[Int],
...
```

I think the problem might be simply syntactical, however any other combinations with parens doesn't help.

*Edit*:

It compiles, however the JSON doesn't parse. It simply doesn't build my objects.

If I try this:

`(__ \ 'lat).read[Option[String]].map(_.toInt)`

I get an error:

`value toInt is not a member of Option[String]`

However in the REPL this works:

```
val stringOpt: Option[String] = Some("10")
stringOpt.map(_.toInt)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(10)
```

Comment: don't just say "this doesn't work".  Tell us why, what error does the compiler give you?

Comment: The code compiles however the incoming json doesn't get deserialized into my objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When debugging `Reads`, its helpful to look through the validation errors and exceptions that may occur from `validate[T]`.  You haven't posted your case class, but deserializing fields that are formatting as `xx.xx` to `Int` doesn't make any sense. You'll get a `NumberFormatException` when calling `"20.20".toInt`. `Double` would probably make more sense,  or `BigDecimal`.

This works:

```
case class Location(lat: Option[Double], lon: Option[Double])

implicit val reads: Reads[Location] = (
    (__ \ "lat").readNullable[String].map(_.map(_.toDouble)) and 
    (__ \ "lon").readNullable[String].map(_.map(_.toDouble))
)(Location.apply _)
```

Of course, if `lat` or `lon` is not a number, this will throw an exception.

The best way to handle this is to not format your numbers in JSON as strings at all. Then the play-json library will handle the errors for you. If this is not possible, you might consider using `Try`.

```
(__ \ "lat").readNullable[String].map(_.flatMap(x => Try(x.toDouble).map(Some(_)).getOrElse(None)))
```

Comment: I realized the silly Int / Double mistake just after posting! However I'm curious in your answer why you used `readNullable` ? Is that akin to writing `read[Option[String]]` ? And yes, unfortunately this is an external endpoint that I don't have control over